# How do I import xyz and roll/pitch/yaw from csv file to Blender?

Tags: blender

I want to know if it is possible to import data of attitude and position (roll/pitch/yaw & xyz) from a comma separated file to Blender?

I recorded data from a little RC car and I want to represent its movement in a 3D world.

I have timestamps too, so if there's a way to animated the movement of the object it'll be superb!!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Best Regards.

Comment: what version of Blender are you using ? 2.4x or 2.5x ?

Comment: The very last one, because of the rush I finally implement it in Google Earth doing a route XML file, is not what I wanted but it served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blender v2.62:

If you have a file "positions.log" looking like:

```
-8.691985196313894e-002;  4.119284642631801e-001; -5.832147659661263e-001
 1.037146774956164e+000;  8.137243553005405e-002; -5.703274929662892e-001
-3.602584527944123e-001;  8.378614512537046e-001;  2.615265921163826e-001
 6.266465707681335e-001; -1.128416901202341e+000; -1.664644365541639e+000
 3.327523280880091e-001;  4.488553740582839e-001; -2.449449085462368e+000
-7.311567199869298e-001; -1.860587923723032e+000; -1.297179602213110e+000
-7.453603745688361e-003;  4.770473577895327e-001; -2.319515785100494e+000
 1.935170866863264e-001; -2.010280476717868e+000;  3.748000986190077e-001
 5.201529166915653e-001;  3.952972788761738e-001;  1.658581747430548e+000
 4.719198263774027e-001;  1.526020825619557e+000;  3.187088567866725e-002
```

you can read it with this python script in blender (watch out for the indentation!)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from math import *
from bpy.props import *
import os
import time

# Init
position_vector = []

# Open file
file = open("C:\\Work\\position.log", "r")

# Loop over line in file
for line in file:

    # Split line at ";"
    splittet_line = line.split(";")

    # Append new postion
    position_vector.append(
        Vector((float(splittet_line[0]),
                float(splittet_line[1]),
                float(splittet_line[2]))))

# Close file
file.close()

# Get first selected object
selected_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

# Get first selected object
for position in position_vector:
    selected_object.location = position
```

This reads the file and updates the position of the first selected object accordingly. Way forward: What you have to find out is how to set the keyframes for the animation...

Answer (score 3):

A slight modifcation, making use of the csv module

```
import bpy
import csv

position_vectors = []

filepath = "C:\\Work\\position.log"

csvfile = open(filepath, 'r', newline='')
ofile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in ofile:
    position_vectors.append(tuple([float(i) for i in row]))

csvfile.close()
```

This will get your points into Blender. Note the delimiter parameter in csv.reader, change that accordingly. With a real example file of your RC car we could provide a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this python snippet to add to the solutions above

```
obj = bpy.context.object

temporalScale=bpy.context.scene.render.fps
for lrt in locRotArray:
   obj.location = (lrt[0], lrt[1], lrt[2])
   # radians, and do you want XYZ, or ZYX?
   obj.rotation_euler = (lrt[3], lrt[4], lrt[5])
   time = lrt[6]*temporalScale
   obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=time)
   obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=time)
```

I haven't tested it, but it will probably work, and gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

With a spice2xyzv file as input file. The script writed by "Mutant Bob" seems to work.

But the xyz velocity data are km/s not euler angles, I think, and the import does not work for the angles.

```
# Records are <jd> <x> <y> <z> <vel x> <vel y> <vel z>
#   Time is a TDB Julian date
#   Position in km
#   Velocity in km/sec
2456921.49775 213928288.518 -446198013.001 -55595492.9135 6.9011736 15.130842 0.54325805
```

Is there a solution to get them in Blender? Should I convert velocity angle  to euler, is that possible in fact?

I use this script :

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from math import *
from bpy.props import *
import os
import time

# Init
position_vector = []

# Open file
file = open("D:\\spice2xyzv\\export.xyzv", "r")

obj = bpy.context.object

temporalScale=bpy.context.scene.render.fps

for line in file:
    # Split line at ";"
    print("line = %s" % line)
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    locRotArray = line.split(" ")
    print("locRotArray  = %s" % locRotArray )
    #for lrt in locRotArray:
    print(locRotArray[1])
    obj.location = (float(locRotArray[1]), float(locRotArray[2]), float(locRotArray[3]))
    # radians, and do you want XYZ, or ZYX?
    obj.rotation_euler = (float(locRotArray[4]), float(locRotArray[5]), float(locRotArray[5]))
    time = float(locRotArray[0])*temporalScale
    print("time = %s" % time)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=time)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=time)
```